# The grammar and meaning of "Surveying the slow parade..." and onward

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, gerunds

> I was riding my bike through a small town when traffic slowed to
>   crawl. Peering ahead, I saw an officer beside his patrol car holding
>   what appeared to be a gun. But as I got closer, I realized that it was
>   really a hair dryer. "what's up with that?" I asked. "our gun is being
>   repaired," said Coup. **Surveying the slow parade of the cars, he
>   added, "But they don't know that."**

I understood all grammar and meaning in this text except the part where it starts with the word **surveying**? So, I need the grammar and meanings of them.

Comment: Was it a radar speed gun that the officer appeared to be holding?

Comment: I suppose the hairdryer just has a really sleek design perhaps

Answer (score 2):

The word "surveying" is the continuous form or `present participle` of the verb "to survey" which means "to carefully watch and study something". [↗ View Google Definition](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1SQJL_enBB825BB825&q=Dictionary#dobs=survey)

The `present participle` and `past participle` forms of verbs are used to describe nouns much like adjectives, but describe what the noun is doing or what has been done to the noun respectively, and can be followed by phrases that represent what would have followed the verb.

**E.g.**

---

- The boy running down the hill sees a cat.
- Eating an apple, Sophia bites her lip.

---

The phrase "running down the hill" describes what "the boy" is doing when he sees the cat, and the phrase "eating an apple" describes what "Sophia" is doing when she bites her lip.

As such, the phrase "surveying the slow parade of the cars" in your paragraph, is describing what "he", which refers to "the cop", is doing when he "added 'But they do not know that' ".

Altogether, the sentence is saying that the cop was carefully watching and studying the "slow parade of cars" when he said, "But they don't know that".

---

### **More definitions**

- *parade* - a series of people or things appearing or being displayed one after the other.
- *added* - from *to add* - say as a further remark (say more) / join (something) to something else  / contribute (an enhancing quality) to something

---

### **Participle Examples**

***to survey***

- *Present Participle* - surveying
- *Past Participle* - surveyed

> *The soldiers are **surveying** the land for mines left after the war.*
>   - The ***surveying*** soldiers.
>
> *The area was **surveyed** yesterday to see if it is safe to build a house.*
>   - The ***surveyed*** area.

↓ **N.B.** Many *past participle* forms of verbs are the same as the *past tense*, but not all.

***to write***

- *Present Participle* - writing
- *Past Participle* - written

> *Ariel is **writing** a letter to the committee.*
>   - The ***writing*** girl.
>
> *The notices are **written** on the board for everyone to see.*
>   - The ***written*** notices.

***to take***

- *Present Participle* - taking
- *Past Participle* - taken

> *The thief is **taking** the money from the vault.*
>   - The ***taking*** thief.
>
> *The books are **taken** from the office every Tuesday.*
>   - The ***taken*** books.

Comment: This is the best  explanation l have seen on this website so far . Thank you so much Stephen .

Comment:  thanks (I need more characters...that should do)